# How do I add a UIAlertView on the press of a button?

Tags: uibutton, uialertview

I want to create a UIAlertView on the press of a button. In my game I would like to tell the player a little about the level before they proceed and I would like to do it with a UIAlterView. How do I do that to make it come when they press a button?

Comment: you should study/google the basics first and then ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action button function put this code:

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of the popup"
                                                  message:@"The message to display to the user"
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
[message show];
```

If you don't use ARC you should release the allocated variable after using the "show" method:

```
[message release];
```

Hope this helps.

Source: http://www.mobiledev.nl/popup-message-in-ios/

Comment: Thank you, now how do i make that uialertview button go to another view controller . sorry if this is stupid but i am a beginner

Comment: I'd recommend you to read and follow this tutorial, it helped me understand how to do exactly what you want: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/